# NextAuth and TypeOrm - Retrieve a repository in an api endpoint

Tags: next.js, repository, adapter, typeorm, next-auth

I've got an **NextJS** app with **NextAuth** and **TypeORM**.
I'm looking for the possibility to **retrieve a specific user or custom entity in an api endpoint.**
However, i don't know how to do this properly.
I don't want to re-initialize the connection options on every api for TypeORM and would like to use the connection set by the adapter. (idea of a singleton).

Someone has any idea on how to achieve that ?

**Have a nice day !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know if I got your question, but  I think the best way of doing it is by creating your Entities, connecting via TypeORM with `synchronize` option `true`.
It will create and update all your tables and columns from your defined model.

Then, you can create another connection to use in your api routes.
I don’t think Vercel can deploy it with a single connection without a custom implementation server implementation.

This guy made a solution that you can try

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12254#discussioncomment-19769

This is another approach to the same function

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/6241#issuecomment-643690383